# how does main function knows the void function is executed successfully in C?

Tags: c, return, return-value

In this simple program in C

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void hello() {
    printf("hey i am from void function\n");
}  

int main() {
    hello();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
hey i am from void function
```

After successful execution of `hello` function, the control returns to main function and program terminates.

How does the `main` function know that the called `void` function is executed?

Comment: What makes you think`main` function *knows* a function is called??

Comment: If a `int main` function executed, it returns a value to operating system, saying it has executed.. whenever a `int` function is called, it returns value indicating that is has finished it execution. but how void function tells it has finished its execution? @Darth-CodeX

void function returns nothing right?

Comment: I just tried to know about it... @Darth-CodeX

Comment: If the function `hello` does not have a return value, then the function `main` will not receive any information from the function `hello`. Therefore, the function `hello` has no way of telling `main` whether it was successful or not (unless you use some other channel for conveying this information, such as a global variable). The function `main` will lose control of the program when it calls the function `hello` and will regain control when that function returns.

Comment: "when that function returns" what that function returns? @AndreasWenzel

Comment: @ASWIN When the function `hello()` returns. Exiting is sometimes called returning, even for void functions.

Answer (score 2):

> How do the main function knows that the called void function is executed?

It doesn't know.

And it doesn't need to know.

Maybe the function isn't even called! Maybe the compiler just did the `printf` in `main`.

The C standard only cares about the behavior of the program, i.e. what observable   effects the program has. The C standard doesn't care how it's done. Only that the observable effects are correct.

For your program all that matters is that "hey i am from void function" is written to standard out. As long as that is done, it doesn't matter how it is done.

With optimization turned on, e.g. `-O2`, for your program it's very likely that the compiled binary will call `puts` directly from `main`. No call of `hello`. No call of `printf`. Just a single call of `puts`.

Example from godbolt.org:

```
.LC0:
        .string "hey i am from void function"
hello():
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        jmp     puts
main:
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        call    puts
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
```

Notice how `hello` isn't called.

Answer (score 2):

When a function is executed, there are 3 possibilities:

1. It returns
2. It ends up in endless execution and never returns
3. The program is terminated (e.g. due to a critical fault caught by the OS or CPU)

Thus, `main()` "knows" that `hello()` returned by the fact that the instruction following the function call is executed. I.e.:

```
int main() {
    hello();
    printf("Returned from hello()\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Whether or not `hello()` was *successfully* executed depends on the definition of "successful".

From the perspective of the code itself, one could say that "successful" simply means that the function returned. This seems to be what is meant by "succesful" in this question.

If the author of the program wants another definition of "successful", then (s)he needs to implement it and either return a "success/failure" status or set an error flag in case of error. In any case, a check of this status would then need to be implemented in `main()`.

For example (requiring that `hello()` is only called once):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool error_flag = false;

void hello() {
    static bool first_run = true;
    if(first_run)
    {   // OK to run hello() once
        printf("hey i am from void function\n");
        first_run = false;
    }
    else
    {   // Not allowed to run hello() more than once
        error_flag = true;
    }
}  

int main() {
    int return_code = 0;

    error_flag = false; // Reset error flag
    hello();

    if(!error_flag)
    {   // No error raised: all is good
        printf("Hello() was successful\n");
    }
    else
    {   // Error raised: indicate to OS that the program was not successful
        printf("Hello() failed\n");
        return_code = 1;
    }

    return return_code;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you choose to imagine that a function "knows" or can perceive anything, then you should also imagine that a function can recognize *directly* when a function call it performs finishes executing.  If the called function returns a value, then the caller uses its perception that the call has completed to know that it can access the return value, not the other way around.

HOWEVER, in C, as in most languages with functions, when one function calls another, it's not as if the first *actively* waits for the second to execute.  There is no virtual actor working on behalf of the caller, looking for signs that the called function has completed.  Rather, the caller resumes *as a consequence* of the called function terminating.

If the called function returns a value then that value is available upon resumption for the caller to use as it sees fit -- exactly as, say, the value of an arithmetic operation is available for use in the function in which that expression is evaluated.  This too is a consequence of the called function completing, not a signal of that.

There's nothing more to say at the level of the C language.  It works that way because that's what the language specifications say.  If you want to look deeper then we have to say that compilers generate environment- and architecture-specific machine code that produces the required behavior.  At this level, it is ordinarily the transfers of control to the subprogram code and back that are directly supported by the instruction set. Procedures for passing parameters and returning values are typically established by convention, not supported directly in hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Any code is just a set of **valid** instruction for the CPU nothing else, `main()` function does not know anything it just performs the instructions mentioned in `hello` function and then performs the instruction you wrote next i.e., `return 0`.

Your `void` function does NOT have to tell anything to `main()` function, when its instruction set is completed it returns automatically.

```
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Here's the assembly output of your program from GCC (`-masm=intel`):

```
.LC0:
        .string "hey i am from void function"
hello:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        call    puts
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     eax, 0
        call    hello
        mov     eax, 0
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

1. In the section `.LC0` your string constant is defined.
2. In the section `hello` it calls the `puts` function, which is optimized by GCC as there's no formatting going-on.
3. In the section `main` a call to `hello` executed and just after that instruction set is completed making the program exists with `0` as its written in the assembly:

```
        mov     eax, 0
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Comment: what does it mean `ret` under hello? in general `ret` means return..but thats a void function..why does it contains that opcode?

Comment: before `ret` there is `nop` which is short for no operation

Comment: @ASWIN https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_280.html

Answer (score 0):

> How do the main function knows that the called void function is
> executed?

It does not - as the processor is executing the code in the function.
When the function is called the processor saves the position where it needs to return (in this case it will be `return 0` statement) when the function terminates. When the called function returns `main` function continues from the next statement.